# Set value of PayPal Buy Now Button

Tags: button, paypal

I am setting up a simple shopping cart type system, and i was wondering how i set the value of a paypal button? Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PayPal has rather extensive documentation on their buttons. I suggest you visit PayPal's website for their full documentation.

When you create a Buy It Now button using the PayPal interface, it asks you to enter the price. If you are creating one programmatically, then the documentation provides details on setting a wide range of the values including the price, currency, etc.

You can find all of this information by logging into PayPal and then Choosing the "Merchant Services" tab. Start with the "Buy Now" link in the Create button section.

Comment: any links that might be useful?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal will [generate the code for you](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-designer&factory_type=buynow).